# transition of the relation among real-valued functions?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

We say $f$ is over $g$ is for all $x\in S_f^g$, there exists $y\in S_g^f$ such that $x<y$, where
$S_f^g=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f(x)<g(x)\}$. Then I want to prove or disprove if $f$ over $g$ and $g$ over $h$, then $f$ is over $h$.

I have the following proof. Can anyone help me to check if its valid?

$f$ over $g$ means for all $x$ such that $f(x)<g(x)$, there exists an $y>x$ such that $f(y)>g(y)$. Similarly $g$ over $h$ means that for all $t$ such that $g(t)<h(t)$, there exist $s>t$ such that $g(s)>h(s)$

Thus let arbitrary $u$ be such that $f(u)<h(u)$, then by the definition of $g$ is over $h$, there is an $s$ such that $f(s)<h(s)<g(s)$, thus, by the definition of $f$ is over $g$, the result follows.

Is this proof looks valid? I guess the only unconvincing part is that can we really deduce $f(s)<h(s)<g(s)$? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not valid. The first thing you needed to work out was the statement you need to show.

- For all $u$ with $f(u) < h(u)$, there is a $v$ with $u < v$ and $h(v) < f(v)$.

You start off with an arbitrary $u$ with $f(u) < h(u)$, which is good. But your next step just doesn't follow. The definition of $g$ over $h$ does not mention either $f$ at all, so it certainly does not give you $f(s) < h(s)$. Neither does your assumption give us this, because there is no reason to expect that $s = u$.

A second smaller issue is that the definition of $g$ over $h$ does not even give you *directly* that there exists an $s$ with $h(s) < g(s)$. But the reason this is small is that a trivial additional argument does show the existence of such an $s$. But there is still no relationship between $s$ and $u$ or $f$.

---

You need to back off and examine this more. Try to think of examples of functions $f$ and $g$ with $f$ over $g$. What does that say about their behavior? If $f$ is constant, what would $g$ have to look like for $f$ to be over $g$? If $g$ were constant, what would $f$ have to look like? Can $f$ be over $g$ and $g$ be over $f$ at the same time?

Comment: Hi, I have tried to draw some graph, and my intuition is that if $f$ is over $g$, then it means after some point $a$, $f(y)-g(y)$ should change signs for some collection of $y>a$...e.g if $f$ is constant, then the last part of $g$ must below $f$. And   $sin(x)$ and $-sin(x)$ should be an example of $f$ over $g$ and $g$ over $f$? How can I proceed next? Thanks!!

Comment: Consider $f(x) = \frac 12$ and $g(x) = \sin x$ for another example of two functions that are both over each other, which shows that the "last part" of $g$ need not remain below $f$ for $f$ to be over $g$. Now that you have a better feel for how these function behave, go back and take a look at what you are trying to prove. One important trick for figuring out how to prove something is to try to disprove it instead. The problems you encounter in disproving can guide you in proving. Can you construct a counter-example?

Comment: Hi my thought: if we take $g(x)=sin (x)$ and $f(x)=0.5$, $h(x)=0.6$. Then we must have $f$ is over $g$ and $g$ is over $h$ right? But in this case, $f$ never is over $h$. Am I correct this time?

Comment: Yes. The claim is not true.

Comment: Thank you very much!